# PythonTeX expansion of LaTeX macros

Tags: macros, expansion, pythontex

I found this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515463/pythontex-using-latex-macros-in-pyblock) by the creator of PythonTeX himself. However, running the below code doesn't work for me; I get an error `"Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{pyblock}"`. I'm not convinced that the `\pyc` command is actually having the macro expanded.

Where am I going wrong? I'm trying to use package `keyval` to provide a nice interface to some TeX commands which pass the values on to Python, but in order to do that I need to be able to expand the TeX macros which are the key-values so that Python may consume them.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \pyc{mytext = """\lipsum[4]"""}
    
    \begin{pyblock}
    print(mytext)
    \end{pyblock}
\end{document}
```

I've created an even simpler example below.

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\def\x{2}
\begin{document}
    \pyc{print(\x)}
\end{document}

* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 8:
    File "C:\Users\aosborne\AppData\Local\Temp\<outputdir>\py_default_default.py", line 50
      print(\x)
  SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Comment: Just a guess from looking at the documentation, but perhaps add `\printpythontex` after the `pyblock` environment which apparently is not intended to produce output.

Comment: I don't think it is the pyblock - I put an even simpler example in my question above.

Comment: I don't know why but with `standalone` replaced with `article`, and package `pythontex` loaded with option `gobble=auto`, it works.

Comment: Yes! I literally found that 5 minutes ago.

Comment: @aosborne I know, I just used your "answer" and added the "close" proposal so that the question can be closed. This will make it easier for other people to see what happened.

Answer (score 1):

[how to pass section numbers to python in pythontex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477151/how-to-pass-section-numbers-to-python-in-pythontex)

This is the answer. Use `\setpythontexcontext{x=\x}` and access it by `\pyc{pytex.context.x}`.

Comment: +1 I vote to close the question because there is already an answer. Thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm new to stackexchange.